# How to run PySpark on AWS EMR with AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-lambda, amazon-emr

How may I make my PySpark code to run with AWS EMR from AWS Lambda? Do I have to use AWS Lambda to create an auto-terminating EMR cluster to run my S3-stored code once?

Comment: To run PySpark, you use EMR. To launch EMR, you can use various options including the AWS console, awscli, or a Lambda function. You don't have to use Lambda, but you could if it makes sense e.g. the EMR cluster launch is triggered by data arriving in an S3 bucket.

Comment: Do you have any resources on this that I can refer to?

Comment: Assuming that you use Python, the boto3 library is what you would use to launch an EMR cluster. The boto3 documents explain in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You need transient cluster for this case which will auto terminate once your job is completed or the timeout is reached whichever occurs first.

You can access this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-longrunning-transient.html) on how to initialise the same.

Comment: can we also run python script on S3

Answer (score 0):

What are the processes available to create a EMR cluster:

> 1. Using  [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html)
>      /  [AWS
>      CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-cluster.html)
>      / [Java
>      SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/calling-emr-with-java-sdk.html)
> 2. Using [cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticmapreduce-cluster.html)
> 3. Using Data Pipeline

Do I have to use AWS Lambda to create an auto-terminating EMR cluster to run my S3-stored code once?

> **No**. It isn’t mandatory to use lambda to create an auto-terminating cluster.
>
> You just need to specify a flag `--auto-terminate` while creating a cluster using boto3 / CLi / Java-SDK. But this case you need to submit the job along with cluster config. [Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-longrunning-transient.html)
>
> **Note:**
>
> *Its not possible to create an auto-terminating cluster using cloudformation. By design, CloudFormation assumes that the
>   resources that are being created will be permanent to some extent.*
>
> *If you REALLY had to do it this way, you could make an AWS api call to
>   delete the CF stack upon finishing your EMR tasks.*

How may I make my PySpark code to run with AWS EMR from AWS Lambda?

> You can design your lambda to [submit spark
>   job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html).
>   You can find an example
>   [here](https://blog.ippon.tech/transient-cluster-on-aws/#:~:text=Lambda%20function%20creates%20the%20EMR,to%20the%20subscribers%20using%20SNS.)

In my use case I have one parameterised lambda which invoke CF to create cluster, submit job and terminate cluster.

Comment: How can we run .py script on S3 as the example stated above expects jar  ( which means scala/java )

Comment: In place of `.jar` put your `.py` file. No need to put class name in case of python. And of course there are other config needed such as setting env variable PYSPARK_PYTHON to python executable path. You can find more details in spark docs.

Comment: hello, i tried but its failing may be i am missing something basic, do u hv a working example, my attempt is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62928662/facing-error-while-trying-to-create-transient-cluster-on-aws-emr-to-run-python-s/62928841?noredirect=1#comment111283662_62928841