# Facing error while trying to create transient cluster on AWS emr to run Python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am new to aws and trying to create a transient cluster on AWS emr to run a Python script. I just want to run the python script that will process the file and auto terminate the cluster post completion. I have also created a keypair and specified the same.

**Command below :**

`aws emr create-cluster --name "test1-cluster" --release-label emr-5.5.0 --name pyspark_analysis --ec2-attributes KeyName=k-key-pair --applications Name=Hadoop Name=Hive Name=Spark --instance-groups --use-default-roles --instance-type m5-xlarge --instance-count 2 --region us-east-1 --log-uri s3://k-test-bucket-input/logs/ --steps Type=SPARK, Name="pyspark_analysis", ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE, Args=[-deploy-mode,cluster, -master,yarn, -conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true, -executor-memory,1g, s3://k-test-bucket-input/word_count.py, s3://k-test-bucket-input/input/a.csv, s3://k-test-bucket-input/output/ ] --auto-terminate`

**Error message**

```
zsh: bad pattern: Args=[
```

**What I tried :**

I looked at the args and the spaces and if accidental characters are introduced or not but does not look like. Surely my syntax is wrong but not sure what I am missing.

**What command is expected to do:**

its expected to execute word_count.py by reading the input file a.csv and generating the output in b.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with the use of **spaces** in `--steps`. I formatted the command, so its a bit easier to read where are the spaces (or luck of them):

```
aws emr create-cluster \
    --name "test1-cluster" \
    --release-label emr-5.5.0 \
    --name pyspark_analysis \
    --ec2-attributes KeyName=k-key-pair \
    --applications Name=Hadoop Name=Hive Name=Spark \
    --instance-groups --use-default-roles \
    --instance-type m5-xlarge --instance-count 2 \
    --region us-east-1 --log-uri s3://k-test-bucket-input/logs/ \
    --steps Type=SPARK,Name="pyspark_analysis",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[-deploy-mode,cluster,-master,yarn,-conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true,-executor-memory,1g,s3://k-test-bucket-input/word_count.py,s3://k-test-bucket-input/input/a.csv,s3://k-test-bucket-input/output/] \
    --auto-terminate
```

Comment: hello Marcin, many thanks for quick help. I do have input file and script in place but now i am getting another error zsh: no matches found: Type=SPARK,Name

Comment: I the docs for [--steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-cluster.html) `SPARK` is not listed as one of the Types available. Thus maybe have to exactly check all the arguments. I could only fix the original error reported.

Comment: @akashsharma No problem. Hope it will worked out. Sorry, couldn't help more.

Comment: In case others are still getting `zsh: no matches found: Type=...` after removing spaces. It didn't work for me until I _also_ removed the brackets `[...]` around the `Args=` list.

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing everything in quotes

```
aws emr create-cluster \
    --name "test1-cluster" \
    --release-label emr-5.5.0 \
    --name pyspark_analysis \
    --ec2-attributes KeyName=k-key-pair \
    --applications Name=Hadoop Name=Hive Name=Spark \
    --instance-groups --use-default-roles \
    --instance-type m5-xlarge --instance-count 2 \
    --region us-east-1 --log-uri s3://k-test-bucket-input/logs/ \
    --steps Type="SPARK",Name="pyspark_analysis",ActionOnFailure="CONTINUE",Args=[-deploy-mode,cluster,-master,yarn,-conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true,-executor-memory,1g,s3://k-test-bucket-input/word_count.py,s3://k-test-bucket-input/input/a.csv,s3://k-test-bucket-input/output/] \
    --auto-terminate
```

Visit here for more info
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html

and yes spark can be used

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "Add Spark Step Cluster" --release-label emr-5.30.1 --applications Name=Spark \
--ec2-attributes KeyName=myKey --instance-type m5.xlarge --instance-count 3 \
--steps Type=Spark,Name="Spark Program",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[--class,org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi,/usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar,10] --use-default-roles
```

Comment: any idea if SPARK can be used as Type to trigger python script

Comment: yes, i think that needs jar, I have many python scripts, i am migrating from my on premise cluster to aws. So I want to try running python scripts hosted on S3. any idea how to configure them

Comment: You can also submit pyspark codes `aws emr add-steps --cluster-id yourclusterid --steps Type=spark,Name=SparkWordCountApp,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn, --conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false,--num-executors,2,--executor-cores,2,--executor-memory,1g,s3://yourbucketname/yourcode.py,s3://yourbucketname/yourinputfile.txt,s3://yourbucketname/youroutputfile.out], ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE`

Comment: ok thanks. i am trying to add similar step but  as part of create cluster so that i can auto terminate